# ng-repeat with nested arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I receive the below data from my `REST API`

```
[
  {
    // restaurant details
    },
    "city": {}, // city details
    "location": {}, // location details
    "menu_categories": [
      {
        // menu_categories details
        "menu_items": [
          {
            // menu_items details
            "menu_modifier_groups": [
                {
                // menu_modifier_groups details
                "menu_modifier_items": []
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

In this data, I'm fetching a single restaurant with its `menu_categories` that then has a child `menu_items` which then has a child `menu_modifier_groups` which then has a child `menu_modifier_item`.

As you can see I have arrays nested within each other.
I want to use `ng-repeat` to group `menu_items` under `menu_categories`. something like below;

```
menu_category 1
    menu_item 1
    menu_item 2
menu_category 2
    menu_item 3
    menu_item 4
```

Also how can I use `ng-repeat` on just one for the array? I have the data assigned to `$scope.restuarant`

Any guidance appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can try this (instead of title you can use whatever property you have set):

```
<ul>
    <li data-ng-repeat="category in restaurant.menu_categories">
        {{ category.title }}
        <ul data-ng-if="category.menu_items">
            <li data-ng-repeat="item in category.menu_items">{{ item.title }}</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a tree view to display the data

Take a look at this : http://ngmodules.org/modules/angular.treeview
or this link https://github.com/eu81273/angular.treeview ( it the same )

it take for example this data :

```
$scope.treedata = 
[
    { "label" : "User", "id" : "role1", "children" : [
        { "label" : "subUser1", "id" : "role11", "children" : [] },
        { "label" : "subUser2", "id" : "role12", "children" : [
            { "label" : "subUser2-1", "id" : "role121", "children" : [
                { "label" : "subUser2-1-1", "id" : "role1211", "children" : [] },
                { "label" : "subUser2-1-2", "id" : "role1212", "children" : [] }
            ]}
        ]}
    ]},
    { "label" : "Admin", "id" : "role2", "children" : [] },
    { "label" : "Guest", "id" : "role3", "children" : [] }
];
```

You can easly adapt the rest api data to this

Answer (score 0):

Working plunker - http://plnkr.co/edit/fjDsJbmd7DIlBK3xrdyu.

To group `menu_items` under `menu_categories` using `ng-repeat`

```
<ul ng-repeat="(key, value) in restaurant" ng-init="outerIndex = $index">
   menu_category {{$index + 1}}
   <li ng-init="innerIndex = $index" ng-repeat="menu_cat in value.menu_categories">
       menu_item  {{($parent.$index*value.menu_categories.length)+($index+1)}}
   </li>
</ul>
```

And the output would be:

```
menu_category 1
- menu_item 1
- menu_item 2

menu_category 2
- menu_item 3
- menu_item 4

menu_category 3
- menu_item 5
- menu_item 6
```

Hope this answered your question.